# Web Scraping a list of specific sites for specific keyworks

Tags: web, web-scraping

I have a list of keywords to search on a list of specific websites and I have been looking for a product/procedure that will do it.

Does anyone have any information on how this could be achieved?

Also is it possible to navigate an entire website automatically using any web scraping tools/techniques to locate a specific keyword?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Google over [`software for web scraping`](https://www.google.lv/search?q=software+for+web+scraping&oq=software+for+web+scraping&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.469j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)
2. Learn some python or other language crawling techniques.

Comment: Hello @IgorSavinkin, I thought as much.  Thank you for your help